# What does 'EST' at the end of a NOTAM's valid time mean?

Tags: faa, notam, time

In this NOTAM below, the valid time is "2006280446-2007312359EST".

EST does not appear in the [FAA NOTAM contractions list](https://www.notams.faa.gov/downloads/contractions.pdf).

[image]

I assumed this EST meant "Eastern Standard Time", but that conflicts with the information shown below in ForeFlight.

This is what ForeFlight shows for the same NOTAM:
[image]

What does this "EST" mean?

Comment: In your ForeFlight screenshot, look at the word directly before "CREATED" in each of the NOTAMS.

Comment: @RalphJ true, and getting an FAA-source is much easier to defend than a private software product's interpretation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If the NOTAM duration is expected to return to service prior to the
> End of Validity time, the time is expressed by using a date-time group
> followed immediately by EST (estimate).  Any NOTAM that includes an
> EST must be canceled or replaced before the NOTAM reaches its  End of
> Validity time. If the NOTAM is not canceled or replaced, it will
> expire at the end  of validity time regardless of EST.

Reference:
https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/notam.pdf#page=7

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Please use the quote formatting for direct quotes from other sources; apart from being good practice it helps people who use screen readers and other tools.

Comment: #page=7 would allow you to link the specific page in the .PDF also. Ie. https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/notam.pdf#page=7

Answer (score 3):

[Estimated](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2015/10/05/2015-25192/change-in-est-usage-in-notice-to-airmen-notam#:%7E:text=The%20NOTAM%20Originator%20must%20cancel,%2C%20on%20September%2023%2C%202015.).

Oddly, this isn't stated explicitly in [JO 7930.2](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1035053), *Notices to Airmen (NOTAM)*.